# Get user information from DN

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have two goals with the below code

1) Get a list of Users who below to a specific AD group
2) Get the email/lastname/first name of all the users that belong to that group

If there is a better way to accomplish both please let me know.

I'm able to get the full DN but I'm not sure how to get the remaining data from the full DN, or if there is a better way to pull this info please let me know.  below is the code I'm using but it gets error:

> `The value provided for adsObject does not implement IADs.`

when I tried to do a DirectorySearcher using the full DN.

```
HashSet<string> User_Collection = new HashSet<string>();

SearchResultCollection sResults = null;
DirectoryEntry dEntryhighlevel = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=Global_Users,OU=Astrix,OU=Clients,OU=Channel,DC=astro,DC=net");
foreach (object dn in dEntryhighlevel.Properties["member"])
{
    DirectoryEntry dEntry = new DirectoryEntry(dn);
    Console.WriteLine(dn);
    DirectorySearcher dSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(dEntry);
    //filter just user objects
    dSearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Base;
    //dSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(dn="+dn+")";
    dSearcher.PageSize = 1000;
    sResults = dSearcher.FindAll();
    foreach (SearchResult sResult in sResults)
    {
        string Last_Name = sResult.Properties["sn"][0].ToString();
        string First_Name = sResult.Properties["givenname"][0].ToString();
        string Email_Address = sResult.Properties["mail"][0].ToString();
        User_Collection.Add(Last_Name + "|" + First_Name + "|" + Email_Address);
    }
```

Speed is important and yes I understand I'm not using HashSet as it's designed.

Answer (score 1):

I always use the [`System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299745).

One of the first things you will see is this: "Connections speeds are increased by using the Fast Concurrent Bind (FSB) feature when available. Connection caching decreases the number of ports used."
with that being said I did not test your code against this for speed you will have to do that your self but this is Microsoft's new library.

Here is my code example:

```
// Create the context for the principal object. 
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,
                                            "fabrikam",
                                            "DC=fabrikam,DC=com");

// Create an in-memory user object to use as the query example.
GroupPrincipal u = new GroupPrincipal(ctx) {DisplayName = "Your Group Name Here"};

// Set properties on the user principal object.

// Create a PrincipalSearcher object to perform the search.
PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher {QueryFilter = u};

// Tell the PrincipalSearcher what to search for.

// Run the query. The query locates users 
// that match the supplied user principal object. 
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = ps.FindAll();

foreach (UserPrincipal principal in ((GroupPrincipal)results.FirstOrDefault()).Members)
{
    string email = principal.EmailAddress;
    string name = principal.Name;
    string surname = principal.Surname;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're walking the group membership of some group in AD...(guessing this off of the member reference above)

Anyway, you need to decide what sort of API you're looking for. The one you're using now is a bit lower level (though you could go lower if you want :)). Going higher level is an option as the previous answer eludes to.

To shake out the code a bit more (and help with perf as you mentioned that it is impt to you):

- Use the same connection you used for the group membership search itself (ie no additional connect/bind)
- Do a base search where the base DN is the user DN, the search filter is (objectclass=*) and the attributes are ONLY the attributes you care about (no *)
- You can remove page size. Paging is a way to ask for many objects in groups (aka pages) but a base search only returns 1 object so it doesn't actually do anything.
- Base search result count should always be 1.

Keep in mind cross-domain issues too. Make sure you test your code with a 2 domain forest where a group of type domain local in domain1 has a member in it from domain 2. That will yield some additional work to get more properties as you need to connect to a DC in the other domain (or a GC if the few properties you care about are all in the GC partial attribute set...)

Also keep in mind security. If you don't have access to these properties for some user in your domain, what does the code do? The code above would fail in a nasty way. :) You might want to handle this more gracefully...

Hope this helps.
~Eric